# How to pass argument of type char ** from Python to C API

Tags: python, c, api

I`m currently trying to pass a list of lists to a API function from a C DLL.
The function looks like this

`void iterate(char **matrix, int rows, int cols)`

Do you have any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by passing a `char **` from Python to C API? How did you get a `char**` in Python? Are you asking how to convert a `PyListObject` to a `char**`?

Comment: I didn`t get char ** in Python ,this is what the API needs as argument.